# R: find the original name of a function passed as argument

Tags: r, function, argument-passing

I have functions `f1` and `f2` that are taking a function as argument, eg:

```
f1 <- function(FUN) {
    ...
}


f2 <- function(FUN)  {
   f1(FUN=FUN)
}
```

From inside function `f1`, I need to find back the original name of the function passed to `f2`, eg `"myFunc"`, but not `"FUN"`.

Basically can we imagine a function `f1` so that `f2(f1(mean))` returns `"mean"`? If `FUN` is anonymous, we can for instance return `NULL` or `NA`.

Is there an easy / standard way to do that in R? I have tried to manually search for identical function code using (but it is not very clean and I am looking for a better solution)

```
fn = unlist(as.list(lsf.str(envir=.GlobalEnv)))
for (f in fn) {
    if (setequal(paste(body(myFunc)),paste(body(f)))) { 
      return(f)
    }
}
```

Comment: There is not enough information here. You need to create a reproducible example. If `FUN` is supposed to be a function, it could be anonymous. What should be returned in such a case?

Comment: @Roland Basically can we imagine a function `f1` so that `f2(f1(mean))` returns "mean"? If FUN is anonymous, we can for instance return NULL or NA. I modified the question with your feedback

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `lazyeval` package too:

```
f1 <- function(FUN) {
  lazyeval::expr_text(FUN)
}


f2 <- function(FUN)  {
  f1(FUN = FUN)
}

f2(f2(f2(mean)))
[1] "f2(f2(mean))"
```

---

This worked for me:

```
f1 <- function(FUN) {
  eval(quote(substitute(FUN)), envir = parent.frame())
}


f2 <- function(FUN)  {
  f1(FUN=FUN)
}

f2(mean)
```

In this case, `f1` evaluates the `substitute(FUN)` call in the f2 environment.

See theese results:

```
> f2(mean)
mean
> f2(function(x) {NULL})
function(x) {
  NULL
}
```

If you want the output to be string, you need to use `deparse`, then f1 can be defined:

```
f1 <- function(FUN) {
  eval(quote(deparse(substitute(FUN))), envir = parent.frame())
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In most situations, following function give the original name.

```
find.original.name <- function(fun) {
    objects <- ls(envir = environment(fun))
    for (i in objects) {
        if (identical(fun, get(i, envir = environment(fun)))) {
            return(i)
        }
    }
}

a <- ls
find.original.name(a)
# [1] ls

a <- glm
find.original.name(a)
# [1] "glm"

a <- function() print("test")
find.original.name(a)
# [1] "a"
```

But if a copy of function (to be precise, it's not a copy) and the original function are in the same environment, this function cannot work correctly...

```
test <- function() print("test")
a <- test
find.original.name(a)
# [1] "a"
```